# Why is IE lacking in Add-on/ Extensions as other browsers?

Tags: internet, windows-explorer, internet-explorer, addons, extension

I have always wondered that .. , perhaps it is directly related to the Trident layout engine? I need a good technical answer.

thanks in advance

Comment: Because the developers up until now didn't want to add this feature

Comment: with IE12, Microsoft wants to make it easier to create addons: http://www.neowin.net/news/internet-explorer-12-ui-overhaul-is-a-blend-of-chrome-and-firefox-adds-extension-support

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft: Managing Add-ons for IE](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/manage-add-ons#ie=ie-11).

> Internet Explorer is **designed to provide an add-on free experience**,
>   and will play HTML5 and many Adobe Flash videos without needing to
>   install a separate add-on.

You'll only be able to install and use add-ons Internet Explorer for the desktop.

There are, however, some [popular addons for IE](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/10-best-internet-explorer-add-ons-extensions-plugins-2014) available.

A more technical answer would be to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions) and see why it's so hard(?) to develop add-ons for IE.